# In sqlalchemy connecting to MySQL , do I need to close after with statement?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to connect the MySQL server. I wrote the code with 'with' statements.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

stmt = "call rax.test_only()"
with engine.begin() as connection:
    connection.execute(stmt)
```

It works fine, but I have a question. After with statement, do I need to close? If so, what level do I need to close? engine level or connection level?
such as

```
engine.close()
```

or

```
connection.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't, because context manage already do that for you.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this question as it is, since the scope of your code is unclear and you have not included your engine's pool configuration. Depending on that the connection might not be closed for good, but released back to the pool of available connections, which usually is desired. In addition to (possibly) handling the connection's lifetime, your with-statement handles a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for both. Let me study something about engine's pool configuration